# How can I insert an embedded image in Outlook with office-js

Tags: javascript, office-js

It is possible to embed a image in outlook email ? With this code outlook will insert a broken image mailBoxItem.body.setSelectedDataAsync

```
var linkToImage = '<img src=\"data:image/'+getTemplateExtension(template.templateType).replace('.','')+";base64," + sasLink + '\"/>';

                         //Add an image as a link
                        if (mailBoxItem.body.setSelectedDataAsync) {
                            mailBoxItem.body.setSelectedDataAsync(linkToImage, {
                                        asyncContext: null,
                                        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
                                    },
                                    function(asyncResult) {
                                        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                                            showMessage("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                                        } else {
                                            showMessage("You successfully wrote in the email body. Click Next to learn more.");
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like currently outlook don't support inserting `<img>` tags which have a base64 encoded image in the `src` element, and requires you to have a full URL of the image instead.

So I wrote a server side script to which I am POSTing the base64 image string. The script saves the image on the server and then return's back the URL.Now  finally you can create an `<img>` tag with the returned URL as `src`,and can be successfully embedded in the message body.

Used the followings code to get it working

```
 var imageBase64Data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...';//truncated the actual base64 data as its too  long
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'https://metalop.com/Word-Cloud-Generator/image-url-generator.php',
     data: {
         image: imageBase64Data
     },
     error: function(e) {
         console.error(e);
     },
     success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         var imageHTML = "<img " +
             "src='" + response + "' img/>";
         console.log(imageHTML);

         //Add an image as a link
         Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).body.setSelectedDataAsync(imageHTML, {
                 coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html,
             },
             function(asyncResult) {
                 if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                     app.showNotification("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                 }
             });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks :) I also made this solution but it's  not accepted we cannot make our images public and keep undying links.